# On Insert Data in Firebase RealTime Database it deletes previous data

Tags: java, android, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on adding a chat module on my application but i have been having an issue when i set new value the previous one gets deleted. My Android source code looks something:-

```
   Map dictMap = new HashMap();
   dictMap.put(Message.chatId,1);
   userMessageRef.child(Message.senderId + "/" + RecieverUID).setValue(dictMap);
   recipientUserMessageRef.child(RecieverUID + "/" + Message.senderId).setValue(dictMap);
```

In The firebase the structure is SenderID, ReceiverID, Plus dictMap but what happens is each time i send a new message the previous one gets deleted.

Comment: Message.senderId + "/" + RecieverUID corresponds always to the same child, assuming that you're sending something from Dude1 to Dude2

Answer (score 1):

You so like this

```
       Map dictMap = new HashMap();
       dictMap.put(Message.chatId,1);
       userMessageRef.child(Message.senderId + "/" + RecieverUID).push().setValue(dictMap);
       recipientUserMessageRef.child(RecieverUID + "/" + Message.senderId).push().setValue(dictMap);
```

In this method creat random id for each message, and json like

```
     RecieverUID + "/" + Message.senderId{
                    id1:message,
                    id2:message,
                  }
```

Comment: With Push(). It will generate another ID but dictionary itself has a unique ID

Comment: @AlexMamo What i'm trying to archive is addict data on the same child each and everytime.